# c# + programming logic - Can I access a constructor object from constructed object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic

Please forgive me not beign super precise about this, but I am a c# noob and only learning programming. This is a problem I can't really test at this moment, but have to make a decision how to approach it.

I have a SampleClass:

```
public class SampleClass {
    string Name;
    SecondClass SecondClass;
    string Attribute;
    public SampleClass (string Name, SecondClass SecondClass)
    {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.SecondClass = SecondClass;
    Attribute = SecondClass.HakunaMatata;
    }
}
```

And a SecondClass

```
public class SecondClass{
    public string HakunaMatata;
    public SecondClass (string HakunaMatata){
    this.HakunaMatata = HakunaMatata;
}
```

so far so good. Now I need to know if I can add to SampleClass a function to change HakunaMatata from Second class?
Like:

```
if (Name == "Simba"){
SecondClass.HakunaMatata = "Dont'w worry, be happy"}
```

by inserting this code into SampleClass, will I change the value of SecondClasses object used to construct SampleClass or is the programm making a copy of it for purpose of construction? Will it change the SampleClass Attribute on the next instance on SampleClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will since `string` is a reference type and your `string Attribute` is actually referring to `SecondClass.HakunaMatata`. BTW, your this line in `SampleClass`

```
Attribute = SampleClass.HakunaMatata;
```

Should be

```
Attribute = SecondClass.HakunaMatata;
```

Comment: Thank you, corrected Attribiute, and thank you so much for clearing this out for me.